# Google Cloud Platform Load Balancer with Cloud Run throws 404 error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, serverless, google-cloud-run, gcp-load-balancer

I'm trying to setup the multi region deployment with Load Balancer that drives traffic to the Cloud Run app which is deployed in the closed region to the visitor by this tutorial https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/multiple-regions

I have a Google Cloud Platform Load Balancer setup with a backend service which points to three regional network endpoint groups each of them linked to a separate instance of Cloud Run app in different regions.

When I'm accessing a Cloud Run app in any region directly by Cloud Run app URL (like this https://cms-us-east1-dpuglk7uja-ue.a.run.app) it works well.

When I'm accessing the app through the load balancer domain in the europe it works good as well.

But when I'm accessing the app through the load balancer domain in any other region (US, Asia) I'm getting a 404 error with message `The requested URL was not found on this server. That’s all we know.`

I've done everything explained in [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/multiple-regions) and not sure what's wrong with that. Here are the regions I'm using: `europe-north1`, `us-east1`, `asia-northeast1`.

Is there any chance that the beta version of the Serverless NEG is still buggy?

Comment: Have all your services the same name but deployed in different regions? From your example, it seems that you name the service with the region in the service name, it should be your issue.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Okay, so I need to have the same Cloud Run service name across all the services in multiple regions, right?

Comment: Correct. Have a try and let me know

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere it worked! Thank you very much! Could you please add an answer so I'll mark it as a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your load balancer configuration is the right one. You have one backend service, and 1 serverless NEG per region.

The condition to have something working is to have the **SAME** Cloud Run service name but deployed in different regions.